# InnoDB transactions - doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, transactions, innodb

I wanted to try out transactions and how they work practically. So I decided to write two scripts in order to test the main function of transactions (handling simultaneous accesses to the database)

I already asked a question here on stackOverflow, and the following was an Edit of that question. But I read through the rules again and I thought it might be wrong to post it under my original question because it's something different. So I ask this in a new question:

My Code (and the database table is set to InnoDB):

On page1.php:

```
$db->query("START TRANSACTION;");

$db->query("SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;");
try {
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 120000000) {
    $i++;
}
var_dump($db->query("INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, 'testvalue')"));
$db->query("COMMIT;");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
$db->query("ROLLBACK;");
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

the `query`-method works. It just queries the string. And the `while`-loop is just for me. I need a bit time to go to the other browser tab to load page2.php:

```
$db->query("START TRANSACTION;");
$db->query("SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;");
try {
    // outputs an array with the data
    var_dump($db->query("SELECT * FROM test", "assoc"));
    $db->query("COMMIT;");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->query("ROLLBACK");
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

With the `SELECT` I get an array with all of the values inside the database table, which was empty at first.

Now I opened page1.php which will insert new data into the `database`. But first it runs through the loop, which takes about 3-4 seconds. Meanwhile, I open up `page2.php`.

From my understanding, page2.php should have waited for page1.php to complete its `transaction`?? But it just loads as usual and outputs an empty Array.

When I refresh `page2.php` after page1.php finished loading, I get the correct output with the new data.

Where is my mistake? I don't quite understand it.

EDIT: Here is another one I tried:

page1.php

```
$db->query("SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;");
$db->query("START TRANSACTION;");
try {

    //print_r($db->query("DELETE FROM test;", "affected"));
    $i = 200;
    while ($i <= 700) {
        var_dump($db->query("INSERT INTO test VALUES ({$i}, 'testvaluetestvaluetestvaluetestvaluetestvalue')"));
        $i++;
    }

    $db->query("COMMIT;");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->query("ROLLBACK;");
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

page2.php

```
$db->query("SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;");
$db->query("START TRANSACTION;");

try {
    var_dump($db->query("SELECT * FROM test", "assoc"));
    $db->query("COMMIT;");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->query("ROLLBACK");
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

While page1.php is not completed, page 2 should output *nothing*, but it outputs the first 70 rows (depending on how fast I reloaded)

Comment: Page 2 doesn't wait for page 1, otherwise you could have some serious performance issues: it reads the database at the point where it's requested, but should only read data that hasn't been modified by page 1.... ie the state of the database prior to any of page 1 inserts/updates/deletes

Comment: [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) might give you some idea on what transactions are all about

Comment: Oh, okay. But I tried another thing as well. on page 1 I inserted like 500 rows into the database, which takes some seconds. Meanwhile I opened page 2 and it did output the first 70 rows, that are being added by page 1. But I can't understand why. Because `autocommit` is disabled so it should (as you said) apply those inserts only AFTER all of them were queried. Maybe I post this code in my question. Maybe there is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

transactions try to avoid locking tables / rows wherever possible to improve concurrency. that is a good thing.

what they are for is to ensure that a set of sql statements all execute as an atomic unit.

meaning if an error occurs all the queries within the transaction are rolled back.

how strict / aggressive the locking is can be controlled with isolation modes, more infos in the mysql documentation.

so it sounds like you are misunderstanding theire purpose, the are not a semaphore mechanism.

Comment: Good answer, but please don't write in all-lower-case here. We have many editors who improve the quality of questions and answers, and we don't want to give them extra work `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior by transactions... What you expected is a pessimistic locking mechanism, but every relational database uses optimistic locking and transaction isolation to make thing faster.

You can read more about this in the [pgsql manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/mvcc.html). I know your question is about mysql, but it does not really matter, because it's about concurrency control conceptions: ACID properties and transaction isolation levels, etc...